# What is a generic word for a person being visited?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a generic word for a person who is being visited.  The opposite of *visitor* according to thesaurus.com is *host.*  That's not what I'm looking for.  A couple examples: an employee being visited by a guest; a student being visited by their parent at school.  I can't think of anything except "visitee" and I couldn't find it officially used anywhere.

Comment: ‘The visited’? Depending on your context and level of formality, you could always just go ahead and use ‘visitee’. It might not be in the dictionaries, but it's a perfectly plain, clear, immediately understandable, and unambiguous word. In an informal context, I'd have no qualms whatsoever in using it.

Comment: It's less common these days, but *visitors* may also be referred to as *callers*. In programming, *caller* has a somewhat different meaning - it's a piece of code that *calls (invokes)* other code. Often that "other code" is called a *subroutine*, especially if it's called by several "higher-level" sections of code. But increasingly it's convenient to refer to the two elements in the interaction as ***caller*** and ***callee***.

Comment: What is wrong with using *host*?

Comment: Host doesn't work. We are talking of an ad hoc visit, not a response to an invitation. The antonym of 'host' is 'guest'. I thing the best idea so far is that of Janus above - 'the visited'. as for his other suggestion 'visitee', I would only use it with a hint of irony.

Comment: A person may be visited.  But also a place may be visited.  Should your word apply in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visitee)

> **visitee** - *noun* - a person who is visited

And from [WordPlays](http://www.wordplays.com/definition/visitee)

> **visitee** - *noun* - the person to whom a visit is made

Comment: I've never heard it used!

Comment: You wouldn't be the only one @WS2. That's the _only_ dictionary i know to have "visitee". But it seems so logical and intuitive that i'd not hesitate to use it on all my visitors and visitees over the coming months!

Comment: That's amazing!  I've looked all over and been using that word for quite a while now, but gave up because I couldn't find it officially used anywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I've decided I will just use visitee.  According to Merriam-Webster.com, the best way to get a word into their dictionary is to just use it.  Since I have no other word to use, I guess I will just try to promote usage of the word.

Comment: Great. You and I are the _Visitees_ -- lesser known than the _Visigoths_ -- but we always have a hot pot of tea ready!